# Is there a standard method for converting visits (i.e., visits to the National Parks) to an equivalent resident population?

Tags: statistics

Purely for my own amusement, I am estimating the violent crime rate in the National Parks.

To make sense out of the low number (about $350$ assaults per $275$ million visits, or $1.3$ per million), I thought of converting visits to an equivalent resident population (ERP).  First, get the best estimate of the average visit length in days (I still need to research this), multiply by the number of visits and divide by $365$.  For example, if the average visit was $12$ hours, the ERP would be about $375,000$. Then compare the rate so derived with that of several cities.

Is there a standard method to do this?  Note that I am not asking for better data.

If this is not an appropriate question for this site, just ignore it.